# awk replace specific column in specific line

Tags: awk

My data file is

```
sdfsdfsdf
1 0.5000 0.5000 0.5000 8 7 90 135  90 135 1 
2 0.5000 0.5000 0.0000 8 7 90 -45  90 -45 1 
3 0.0000 0.5000 0.5000 8 7 90 225  90 225 1 
4 0.5000 0.0000 0.5000 8 7 90 45   90 45  1 
sdfsdfsdf
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
```

and I want to change 7th and 9th column of 2~5 lines, so the result to look like

```
sdfsdfsdf
1 0.5000 0.5000 0.5000 8 7 60 135  60 135 1 
2 0.5000 0.5000 0.0000 8 7 60 -45  60 -45 1 
3 0.0000 0.5000 0.5000 8 7 60 225  60 225 1 
4 0.5000 0.0000 0.5000 8 7 60 45   60 45  1 
sdfsdfsdf
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
```

How do I this with sed or awk?
I tried

```
awk 'NR>=2&&NR<=5{$7="60"}' input.dat > tmp && mv tmp input.dat
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
awk 'FNR==2,FNR==5{$7=$9=60};1' input.dat > tmp
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the 1 for?

Comment: @venki421: `1` is a true expression, which cause `awk` to perform default `print $0`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your script on this way:

```
awk '{if (NR>=2&&NR<=5) $7=60; print}' input.dat > tmp && mv tmp input.dat
```

The problem you observe in your variant is because w/o explicit print clause awk will print the input line

Comment: but this replaces all my file to replaced lines. I only want to change the line 2~5.

Comment: So I just added two more commands, `sed -i "2,5d" input.dat` and
`sed -i "1 r tmp" input.dat` . Is there good way to do this?

Comment: Yes, see my edited answer